# How to delete all variable and store array and some php variable and loop while?

Tags: php, arrays

How to delete all variable and store array and some php variable and loop while ?

This is my code for delete all variable and store `array objResult` and `$c` variable and loop while until complete.

But when i test code. it's will be store only `$c`, How to store `array objResult` too.

And my code not loop while too. how can i do for store `$c` and `array objResult` and `loop while` until complete.

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ''";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $a = "111";
    $b = "122211";
    $c = "333";
    $d = "444";
    $defined_variables = get_defined_vars();
    $variables2keep = array("objResult" , "c");  // not clear $d and array objResult//
    foreach($defined_variables as $variable => $value) 
    if(!in_array($variable, $variables2keep)) unset($$variable);

    echo $objResult["id"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the below:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ''";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
    $a = "111";
    $b = "122211";
    $c = "333";
    $d = "444";
    $variables2keep = array("objResult" , "c", "strSQL", "objQuery");  // not clear $c and array objResult, strSQL and objQuery must remain for while statement to continue through record set
    $defined_variables = get_defined_vars();
    foreach($defined_variables as $variable => $value) {
        if(!in_array($variable, $variables2keep)) unset($$variable);
    }
}
unset($variable);
unset($value);
unset($strSQL);
unset($objQuery);
unset($defined_variables);

print_r(get_defined_vars());
?>
```

Setting $variables2keep above the get_defined_vars will remove this. As $defined_variables, $variable, $value has been set after $defined_variables, you need to unset these too.

You can then get the variables again by: (after the unset)

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

You will see you only have the two variables you want

Comment: but why code not loop while ?
`<?PHP
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ''";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $defined_variables = get_defined_vars();
    $variables2keep = array("objResult" , "variables2keep");  // not clear $i and $variables2keep //
    foreach($defined_variables as $variable => $value) 
    if(!in_array($variable, $variables2keep)) unset($$variable);


echo $objResult["id"];
}
?>`

Comment: $variables2keep = array("objResult" , "c");, should really also include $strSQL and $objQuery, otherwise once while statement goes into next loop it will error as these variables that set the SQL statement and get the record set and being unset

Comment: amended answer, please take a look